# Unable to use express commands through CMD in windows 10

Tags: cmd.exe, node.js

[image: Added path variables]

[image: Using express]

I am getting error *'express' is not recognized as an internal or external command...* I can't find any clear cut procedure for resolving the same.

Comment: You have to close and relaunch cmd after adding to your environmental variables.

Comment: tried that, didn't work